# How to set TraceOutputOptions for Resharper or TeamCity Test Runners

Tags: .net, resharper, teamcity, trace

I am using lots of Tracing throughout my app. I have trace options set to include TraceOptions.DateTime either in code of via the app.config.

But when I run unit tests via Resharper or Teamcity I don't see the DateTime.

How can I set the TraceOutputOptions for the Resharper or TeamCity NUnit test runners?

Answer (score 0):

Found this code-based solution:

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class AssemblySetup
{
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        foreach (var listener in Trace.Listeners.Cast<TraceListener>())
        {
            listener.TraceOutputOptions = listener.TraceOutputOptions | TraceOptions.DateTime;
        }
    }
}
```